# Locate root cause of preprocessor errors - gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to build a big project step by step. I'm working on `Linux` and using `qt-creator` and `gcc` compiler. I include a set of related files in the `.pri` file and then build, test functionality and then add a new set of existing files and so on.

The project compiled successfully then I included a folder containing some header files then when compiled I got many errors in `libc-header-start.h`, `string.h`, `cpu-set.h`, `time.h` and many other stdlib and system files. Errors like `missing binary operator before token (`, `unknown type name __cpu_mask`, `expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token`.

I think these are likely to be preprocessor errors that are caused, for example, if I forget a semicolumn or so, right?

My question is, how can I locate the exact location in the header/source files where all these errors started, for example, the line of code where the semicolumn is missing.

Comment: It's most likely right before the `#include` line of the first header that gets all the errors. If there's another `#include` before that, it's near the end of that header file.

Comment: I'd start by compiling individual .c files. When the first one fails, use `-E` to get preprocessed output, then check what's going on. You can even temporary copy-paste the entire preprocessed file over the original .c file and the try to compile it.

Comment: Assuming that "I included a folder containing some header files" means that you added `-I /some/new/location` to the compilation options, it might be that you should not be directly including the files from the new header directory — their names conflict with standard headers.  Review what's in your new directory.

Comment: You can also use the `gcc -E` option to generate preprocessed files. Then try to compile one of those resulting files using the original command line options and it should give easier to diagnose errors as the line numbers will correspond to the flattened source file.

Comment: Thanks for all of you. The first header files in the errors list is `libc-header-start.h` which is not used at all in my code. Maybe it is included by other system/stdlib headers. The third file is `stdint.h` which looks suspecious to me. I'll investigate there using `gcc -E` and by including individual files. The files name in the folder don't conlict with standard headers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it turned out that you are right. I removed all the files from the folder, then started adding set of files by set of files then compile again. Finally the problem was in a header file named `features.h`. I didn't know that there is a standard header file called `features.h`. After renaming my header file to `features_.h` it compiled. It took me around two working days.

Comment: Observation: I'm not aware of a formal standard (such as ISO 9899:2018, the C standard, or POSIX 2018) that specifies a header `<features.h>`.  Nevertheless, Linux certainly uses `<features.h>` (170+ headers under `/usr/include` on the Linux machine I'm using) so your own `features.h` confused the compilation.  There are some advantages to using `<project/features.h>` notation for a suitable project name — there are also some gotchas and caveats.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is just collecting the comments on my question.**

Here is what can help locating what is the root cause of preprocessor errors:

1. Make sure that the names of your header files don't conflict with standard header files.
2. Check the first file in the errors list. Check where this file is included. If this file is included by another standard header file, check where the parent header file is included in your code. The root cause of the errors may be in the lines before that `#include` statement in your code. For example, you may have forgetten a semi-column before this `#include`.
3. Use `gcc -H file.c` to check all the header files included with `file.c`.
4. Use `gcc -E file.c` to generate a preprocessed version of `file.c`, then you will have the full end picture of your file which you can then investigate.